# swagger php key with associative array value in query

Tags: php, swagger

How to reproduce this with my swagger

```
estates?sqm[from]=1&sqm[to]=2&test[from]=1&sqm[to]=2
```

and in server I faced with exactly what I need

```
$_GET
array (
  'sqm' => 
  array (
    'from' => '1',
    'to' => '2',
  ),
'test' => 
  array (
    'from' => '1',
    'to' => '2',
  ),
)
```

how to describe it in swagger style ?

I try to did like that

```
*   @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="sqm[from]",
 *     in="query",
 *     description="from_sqm",
 *     required=false
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="sqm[to]",
 *     in="query",
 *     description="from_sqm",
 *     required=false
 *   ),
```

but perhpas should be approach use model from schema by ref, right ?